What is the "Black E" in istanbul report (jest coverage report)?
As far as I know, "I" means if-path is not taken, while "E" means else-path is not taken. However, I found there are two versions of "E", one is in yellow font and the other is in black font. (like in the following pic.)
Can anyone tell what's the difference between them?

